# MappedListIterable<Map,String,List<Map<String,Object>>,dynamic> is not as subtype of type Map<dynamic,dynamic>

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have a widget that accepts  **final Map<String, List> transactions;**, but getting the error in title.
How do I parse the response to get the ff. ***Map<String, List>***

Have tried to pass it with:

```
Map<String, dynamic> paymentsResponse = MockResponse.getAccountHistory();
              final Map<String, List<PaymentTransactionList>> transactionList = Map<String, List<PaymentTransactionList>>.from(
                  paymentsResponse['transaction_list'].map(
                          (transaction) => PaymentTransactionList.fromJson(transaction)));

PaymentTransactionHistoryList(paymentsResponse['transaction_list'])
```

**API Response**

```
"transaction_list": [ 
        {
          "july": [
            {
              "stan": 1,
              "timestamp": "2019-02-04 06:22:07",
              "amount": -28755.77,
            }
          ],
        },
      ]
```

**Widget**

```
class PaymentTransactionHistoryList extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map<String, List<PaymentTransactionList>> transactions;

  PaymentTransactionHistoryList(this.transactions);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    transactions.forEach((key, value) {
      widgets.add(PaymentListGroup(key, value));
    });

    return Column(
      children: widgets,
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected UI**

[image: Expected UI]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add ".tolist" at the end

Map<String, List>.from(paymentsResponse['transaction_list'].map(
(transaction) => PaymentTransactionList.fromJson(transaction)).tolist)

it should resolve the issue.Thanks

Comment: Now I am getting, type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Comment: API returns JSON array not json object so that is List not Map.So to get first element use first index. in paymentresponse

Comment: Added expected UI. date is the array key so I needed to the response like that